# Angular2 async/promises in shared-service JSON error at position 0

Tags: angular, asynchronous

I'm getting an error `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` in my shared-service to call an API. I think its because of async request as sometimes the data is available and sometimes this error shows.

The error log is point to this request.

```
public getStores(): void {
 this.retrieveResults().subscribe((results) => {
  this.storesChanged.next(results.Results)
 });
}

public retrieveResults(): Observable<any> {
 return this.http.get(__env.nodeRedApiUrl + __env.storeSummaryPath)
  .map(res => res.json())
}
```

can someone point out why this error is actually showing? I just thought i'd be async call. Can someone direct me how to deal with async/promise in Angular2.

Answer (score 0):

This happens mostly when you return `HTML` instead of `json` as expected. So check backend to make sure `json` is returned.